# How should i ask question politely in this context?

Tags: questions

How should i ask question in this context:

suppose, one of my friends has recently gone to a foriegn country and has been working there for 30 days as a employee.
  But i don't know what work he does and how many hours his duty is.

Now, how should i ask him politely to know what work he does and how many hours he does his duty ? Please help me to ask him.

Answer (score 4):

At least in our culture, it usually isn't rude to ask someone what kind of work he is doing.  So *What sort of work are you doing?* should be fine.  Now, we wouldn't ask how many hours someone does his duty, as it might be taken as if you are trying to find out whether the person is working the hours expected of him or not.  You could just ask *How many hours do they have you working?*

Now, I tend to err on the side of candor rather than tact, personally, so others might disagree with me and that's fine.  The important thing is that you are asking your friend because you care about him.

Comment: And how about asking to a relative ?

Comment: @yubraj - I suppose that's partly cultural, but I would ask my cousins, uncles, brothers and sisters in the same way I would ask my friends.